# How can I add a delay to scroll after each curtain meets in the middle?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, custom-scrolling

I want pause animation for about 20px of scrolling right after each curtain meets in the middle.  Here's my sandbox:

http://www.meetgeraldine.net/2016website/luke-test/

jQuery: http://snippi.com/s/vup8pw0

HTML: http://snippi.com/s/bp5iceg

Is there a way to make the curtains pause for about 20px of scrolling so that the curtain doesn't fade out immediately after the two blocks meet in the middle?

Comment: how about using something like one page scroll https://github.com/leftstick/onepage-scroll

Comment: Not quite what I'm looking for.  I'm trying to pause scrolling in the middle of a normal scrolling page.

Comment: @LukeSmith Curtains? Do you mean after end of each Section(s)?

Comment: @divy3993 Yep.  After each curtain meets in the middle when you scroll down.  Here's the original site with the feature: https://codyhouse.co/gem/3d-curtain-template/

Comment: Promises are your friend here methinks (with a timer in the callback for the delay https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise and https://api.jquery.com/promise/ are some references

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss Can you demonstrate how that would work into my code?  http://snippi.com/s/vup8pw0

Answer (score 0):

If you accept answer based on library there is good solution for you:

**skrollr** https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

You can see tutorial explaining how too use this library to achieve your goal:

**ihatetomatoes** https://ihatetomatoes.net/create-scrolling-slideshow-using-skrollr/

---

The main idea is this: create page with height 100%+20px of your main content and transform with js your content position. You can than stop transform main content when your scroll is between 50%-10px and 50%+10px.

Comment: It sounds good, but not sure how that would translate into my js code.  Can you demonstrate how that would work?

Comment: @LukeSmith I can provide small snippet in jsFiddle. I'm afraid that your code is too complex to stackoverflow good question standard. You should isolate problem and focus only on it (outside of your code). Remember: questions and answer are not only for you, but also for other people. So not everybody has time to get into details of provided source code.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for explaining.  I'm relatively new here so I'm learning as I go.  :)  That would be great if you could provide a snippet.

Comment: Any ideas on this?  Last effort here .. I understand if you wish not to send a small snippet.  :)

Comment: @LukeSmith I can do this tomorrow

Comment: Thanks!  You might want to use the original plugin files .. less messy and more direct for you: https://codyhouse.co/gem/3d-curtain-template/

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a timed animation repeater.  It waits for all the animations to complete, then after the timeout repeats them.  Not 100% sure that is your desire but hopefully you can build from this: (note I did not test this code but it should work.  Requires jQuery for the deferred;

```
function pullCurtains(){
    $.when(
        $('body,html').animate({'scrollTop': target.offset().top}, 500, function(){ animating = false; }).promise(),
        $( '#mything-2' ).animate( { marginLeft : "-100px" }, 500 ).promise(),
        $( '#mything-3' ).animate( { width: 0 }, 1000 ).promise()
    ).done( function(){
        console.log( "All animations complete." );
        setTimeout(function() {
            // trigger new one in 2000 ms
            $(document).trigger('curtian');
        }, 2000);
    });
};
$(document).on('curtian',function(){
    pullCurtains();
});
// do first one
$(document).trigger('curtian');
```